# Local IIS issue in Visual Studio 2013 for WEB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-10

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application on Visual Studio 2013 for WEB. Previously i was using the Visual Studio development server but now as i have selected the Local IIS Web Server i am having a problem which is when i run my code the browser (Chrome) show the URL "http://localhost/MVCDemo/" which is correct but the browser doesn't show any content. Its totally blank. I am running VS in administrator mode. I have checked the IIS which is working fine but the problem is i am not having anything display on the browser. When i am running the same code using the Visual Studio development server it is working absolutely fine and showing the content on the browser. Kindly if anyone knows where i am wrong. Need help regarding this.

Comment: There is nothing in the view source as well.
I have just a simple controller in my Application that do nothing but returns a string. I want to see that string on the browser which is when i am using the VS development server i am able to see that string on the browser but when i use IIS there is nothing to see in the browser. Its blank.

Comment: Did you create a new website in IIS and pointed it to the root folder of your site? Since you're using localhost, that'd Default app in IIS, is it point to you folder and not inetpub\wwwroot?

Comment: I have created a new Web Application not a new website.

Comment: Do you have the Static Content feature installed for IIS? I've run into issues when this hasn't been installed. Just a guess, but it may help. You can find it in Control Panel\Program and Features, select Turn Windows Features on and Off (left sidebar) and then in the dialog go to IIS\World Wide Web Services\Common HTTP Services and there you'll see Static Content.

Comment: Issue Resolved!
What i have done, i just went to control panel\Program and Features, selected Turn Windows Features On and Off and then in the dialog i went to IIS and there i checked all the check boxes. And now its working fine.